# Listbox datatemplate not working

Tags: .net, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I know i have made some silly mistake. But won't able to solve.

This is the xaml code:

```
 <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <toolKit:ListBoxDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True" >

                        <ListBox Height="85" Width="120">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="12233" Foreground="AliceBlue"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>

                    </toolKit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>
                    </Border>
```

And the screen shot is :[image]

Comment: you need to add an ListBoxItem to your ListBox. You have defined the ItemTemplate of the ListBox, but the ListBox has no items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `DataTemplate` property which affects databound data. From the screenshot it looks like you're in VS designer rather than actually running the application. In that case you can set the `ItemContainerStyle`.

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <TextBlock Text="12233" Foreground="AliceBlue" />                        
                  </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListBoxItem>My ListBoxItem</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

If you're just testing the layout then your `DataTemplate` should be fine and can be tested by setting a source for the `ListBox` (such as via `myListBox.ItemsSource` or data binding if have that set up).